# Getting a "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program." error when trying to map ReadUnaligned using DynamicMethod and ILGenerator

Tags: c#, dynamicmethod, ilgenerator

I'm trying to map the IL code for ASP.CORE method ReadUnaligned as defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il) in .NET Frameword using DynamicMethod following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods).

When trying to run the code, I get the "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program." error.

My code:

```
private delegate T ReadUnalignedInvoker<T>(ref byte input);

private delegate TReturn OneParameter<TReturn, TParameter0>(TParameter0 p0);

public static T ReadUnaligned<T, U>(U source)
{
    Type[] methodArgsTypes = { typeof(U) };

    var dm = new DynamicMethod("ReadUnaligned", typeof(T), methodArgsTypes, typeof(SizeHelper).Module);
    ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Unaligned, (byte)0x1);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    OneParameter<T, U> invoker = (OneParameter<T, U>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(OneParameter<T, U>));

    return invoker(source);
    }
```

The call to the method is:

```
var buffer = new byte[Unsafe.SizeOf<TStructure>()];

ReadProcessMemory(_processHandle, baseAddress, ref buffer[0], buffer.Length, out var numberOfBytesRead);

ReadUnaligned<TStructure, byte>(buffer[0]);
```

Where ReadProcessMemory is taken from kernel32.dll

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(SafeProcessHandle processHandle, IntPtr baseAddress, ref byte buffer, int bufferSize, out int numberOfBytesRead);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: should not it be something like `ReadUnaligned<TStructure, byte[]>(buffer);` ? or `byte* ` and using `unsafe` ?

Comment: same issue. it's a problem with invocation rather than with the parameters

Comment: The arguments to read unaligned are pointer or ref types. You need `typeof(U).MakeByRefType()`/`typeof(U).MakePointerType()`. I'm not sure which here (I think Ref). You also need to specify a type token to go along with `ldobj` `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, TYPE)`. Your OneParameter delegate signature is going to be wrong as it needs a byref type also. That's assuming you're trying to copy their implementation

Comment: That seems to be the issue. Calling the Emit with the type fixes the error, but comparing the two side by side, I also need to add the ref to reach the correct result. So, add an answer and I'll mark it as correct.